# How to create dynamic WHEREs with this Select?

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql

Hi I have this select below, it's using with a fixed values to make it easier to test.

The worked and removed selects ( middle selects ) return me 2 sets of data each.

***is there a way to dynamicly get the results of those middle selects and use them to add BETWEENS inside my WHERE ? IN PURE SQL ?***

I should use them to make where clauses, for the higher select.
The first value of the middle selects is gettin in my where properlly but I am losing the second that they each fetch and so my select is return mode data then expected.

```
    select b.bug_id, SUM(b.added) as rework
from    (select distinct b.bug_id, b.added, b.bug_when
        from bugs_activity as b, 
        (select b.bug_id,b.bug_when 
              from bugs_activity as b 
                  where b.bug_id = 13131 
                  and b.fieldid = 8 
                  and b.added like '%Rework%' 
               order by b.bug_when desc limit 500) as worked,
        (select b.bug_id,b.bug_when 
              from bugs_activity as b 
                  where b.bug_id = 13131 
                  and b.fieldid = 8 
                  and b.removed like '%Rework%' 
              order by bug_when desc limit 500) as removed        
        where b.bug_when between worked.bug_when and removed.bug_when
        and b.fieldid = 45
        and b.bug_id = worked.bug_id
        and b.bug_id = removed.bug_id
        and b.bug_id = 13131
        limit 500) as b
group by b.bug_id;
```

I need the where to become something like this ( the worked.bug_when3 is just for explaining can be anything)

```
where b.bug_when between worked.bug_when and removed.bug_when
or
b.bug_when between worked.bug_when2 and removed.bug_when2
or
b.bug_when between worked.bug_when3 and removed.bug_when3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`HAVING`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html) operates on calculated values from the results set, and can be used with aliases.

In your case:

```
SELECT b.bug_id, SUM(b.added) AS rework
FROM
    ...
    LIMIT 500) as b
GROUP BY b.bug_id    
HAVING b.bug_when > 10 AND b.bug_when < 20;
```

You may need to select the fields you require for `HAVING` in your top `SELECT` (i.e. `SELECT  b.bug_id, SUM(b.added) AS rework, b.bug_when`).

**EDIT:**

To have several betweens:

```
HAVING 
  (b.bug_when > 10 AND b.bug_when < 20) 
  OR (b.bug_when2 > 23 AND b.bug_when2 < 41) 
  OR (b.bug_when3 > 152 AND b.bug_when3 < 241)
```

Comment: THANKS, This helps but doesn't solve... I need several ORs with betweens inside like, where b.bug_when between worked.bug_when and removed.bug_when **OR where b.bug_when between worked.bug_when2 and removed.bug_when2.... ** this would be dynamicly created from the results of the selects worked and removed.

Comment: Yes I would like that but not fixed... dynamic. this one I have to write all the ORs I want don't I ?

Comment: Yes, you'll need to write each clause. I'm not sure what you mean by dynamic - you could also construct the query dynamically in your programming language.

Comment: I can't use my backend for this :( have to be in the DB unfortunatly... But thanks anyway, gonna try to use having.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tested the following (using subselects):

```
...
where b.bug_when between
    (select b.bug_when
    from bugs_activity as b
    where b.bug_id = 13131
    and b.fieldid = 8
    and b.added like '%Rework%'
    order by b.bug_when
    desc limit 1)
and
    (select b.bug_when
    from bugs_activity as b
    where b.bug_id = 13131
    and b.fieldid = 8
    and b.removed like '%Rework%'
    order by bug_when
    desc limit 1)
...
```

?

Ps. You should know you should avoid subselects, thought... I believe event making two separate queries to get these two values and then include them within the query would be faster than using subselects...

Comment: Thanks, but this doens't solve it as I will only have one between, I need several. with different time spaces.

Comment: The way I've build it it's working exatcly like you did, only one Werer with a between inside.

Comment: @cfontes I misunderstood your question then.